# "He is very excited that he will <get to> meet his idol." — What meaning does the sentence acquire in adding "get"?

Tags: meaning

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/excited):
**(1)** *He is very excited that he will **get** to meet his idol*.

What does "get" in (1) mean?

Comment: Did you check the definitions of "get" in that dictionary?

Comment: @gotube I had found "[get to do something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get?q=get#:~:text=get%20to%20do%20something%20to%20reach%20the%20point%20at%20which%20you%20feel%2C%20know%2C%20are%2C%20etc.%20something) - to reach the point at which you feel, know, are, etc. something", but this definition is not quite clear to me.

Comment: Keep going down the list, to # 19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sense of *get* means be allowed to or have the opportunity to. Using it in your (or *Oxford*’s) example emphasizes not just the fortunate event but the good fortune that the event reflects, and requires.

In fact, the version without *get* seems somewhat less likely to be uttered naturally by a native speaker of American English, though to some British ears, *get to* still sounds like a bit of an import.

Comment: In the UK, to 'get to' do something is still has an American flavour, and is definitely informal.

Comment: Thanks for that, @MichaelHarvey. Yet another US-UK difference of which I was unaware. Mind if I add it?

Comment: With pleasure! It's not rare or unusual in the UK, and may not sound 'American' to people younger than 40 or 50, but it's still informal.